# How to access discord server channels python

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, oauth, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to build an app that will access discord server channels, and get messages with certain keywords. My problem is, I don't own these servers, and I can't add a bot to it. So I have to use something else to get them. (I am however a part of these servers and have access to said channels).

I looked into oauth, but another answer on SO said it wasn't possible using oauth, so is there a work around?

also how does /guilds/{guild.id}/channels work?

Answer (score 0):

To access the channels and read the messages you will need to have a bot in the guild. Discord limits you from getting guild and its info if your bot is not in it.

To my knowledge, there is no workaround but you may want to ask the experts at the [Discord developers Discord server](https://discord.gg/discord-developers).

The `/guilds/{guild.id}/channels` endpoint is a POST request to get all of a guild's channels. You can see more info on this at [the docs](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#get-guild-channels).